# How can I test app localization?

Tags: ios, ipad, localization

I am testing that a specific app that is in English also works in Hebrew. In iPad Settings, my region is set to Israel, and I've changed the Language Settings from English to Hebrew. I tried restarting the app and the iPad, but the app text is still in English. 
Some of the apps on my iPad have switched to Hebrew, but others are still in English. 
What am I doing wrong?
See screenshots.[some apps are still in English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVvRH.jpg) [some apps are still in English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r3qZ.jpg)

Comment: Maybe they dont have Hebrew names / localization. My apps for example certainly dont have that.

Comment: @luk2302 I tested against another app that I know definitely has app localization including in Hebrew. That app's language text also remained in English on my iPad. So I wanted to ask if my method of testing is correct.

Comment: you can create new schema that langauge you select Hebrew

and when you need to run in Hebrew select schema of that and run it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change schema run options as described here

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html

You will not need to change device/simulator region or language settings.

Comment: Oh, I don't have access to the XCode project - I'm only doing QA for the final build from TestFlight.

Comment: @Nessya Oh, I see. In that case you should check you have right order of preferable languages. First should be Hebrew.